# does gunicorn also execute if __name __ == '__main__'

Tags: python, flask, discord, discord.py, gunicorn

eg I have a command like this `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers = 3 --threads = 3 manage: app` then `manage: app` fetched from `manage.py` file

```py
app = create_app ()
```

does the if `__name __ == '__ main__'` function look like this too

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     flask_thread (func = run)
     client.run (os.getenv ('TOKEN'))
```

executed when running Gunicorn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, gunicorn import your `app` variable and invokes it. The `if` will not be executed.

### Longer Answer

`__name__` is a special variable. If we run your module directly using `python manage.py` then the value is `__main__`. So, the `if` is True.

But, if we run your module imported by another (including gunicorn) using something like `from manage import app` then the value is `'app'` or `'manage.app'` (you can check it by yourself). Without saying, the `if` condition will be False.

Comment: so if we need some config run inside the flask, we need to configure on `create_app` function? @tegar

Comment: @perymerdeka yes, we put the config there